# Clickable url within facebook social plugin

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink, facebook-social-plugins

What is the correct markup for inserting clickable urls/links in the Facebook Social Plugin comments?

I  am not able to find this info in Google, been trying for couple hours now... I even "Binged" it once lol. I know its possible to do since I've seen clickable urls in plugin's comments on many occasions before.

Can someone plz help? Pretty please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert clickable urls in fb plugin, also facebook doesn't allow google to crawl its content. The reason for that you know better facebook is the big rival to google.